# Why does my css animation go outside my window when ever I reload the page, but not when I initially load the page?

Tags: css, animation

I am new to using `css` animations and I wanted to create a simple animation that makes the text slide in from the right to the left side of the screen and it works great... until I reload the page. When the page is reloaded it follows the text onto the screen then when the animation is finished the page displays correctly. Please help!

Here is the code:

```css
.panel-content {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <a href="">
    <div id="panel-1">
      <div class="panel-content">
        <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
        <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you able to post your html?

Comment: I added my HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The scrolling is from the parent container, and especially the body. If you add an `overflow-x: hidden;` to your body element, this should happen.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like the following work as a better solution: https://jsfiddle.net/keLuvbco/5/

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel">
<a href="">   
 <div id="panel-1">
  <div class="panel-content">
   <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
   <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panel-content {
  position: absolute;

  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;

  color: white;
  background-color: blue;

  padding: 20px;

  white-space: nowrap;

  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    left: 150%;
  }

  to {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
```